# Selenium + Ruby + Cucumber. Weird port error

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# language: ru

require 'webdrivers'
require 'selenium-cucumber'


options = Selenium::WebDriver::Options.chrome
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

#driver.get "https://www.google.com"

Given 'Переходим на сайт' do
    driver.get "https://www.google.com"
end

sleep(2)

driver.quit
```

File .feature

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# language: ru

Функция: Тест

    Сценарий: Тест тест
 
        Дано Переходим на сайт
```

The code is as simple as possible. And it works if you remove the Given function and start opening the site not through cucumber. Everything works and opens. But if you open it through Given, an incomprehensible error with ports appears.

> Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
> ./features/step_definitions/test_steps.rb:23:in `nil'

Linux Mint

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to lazy initialization in Selenium.  When you call `driver.get "https://www.google.com"` directly it's initializing the selenium driver and browser connection, so when `driver.quit` is called the connection is up and can then be cleanly shut down. However, when you call

```
Given 'Переходим на сайт' do
  driver.get "https://www.google.com"
end
```

you are defining a block that can be called later, but it doesn't actually execute the `driver.get ...` yet, so the driver to browser connection isn't fully setup yet which leads to `quit` being called on a non-initialized connection and therefore raising an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what can be done to make it work?

Comment: @Belayakasatka you need to actually specify examples that will run, not just define the steps - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby#create-your-specification

Comment: Added the file code to the question .feature Initially, of course, it was.  What can be done to make it work?

Comment: @Belayakasatka Sorry, I can't read russian (I'm guessing that's what language the file is in) but it seems like you need to read up on setting up the cucumber test runner - https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/ruby/